# Android Camera zoom null pointer exception for the zoom controls

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to add zoom controls however, i get null pointer exception when the program gets to do anything with the zoomControls variable, even though, I have defined zoomcontrol in my XML and and my code.

I can see Log "assignement done" but not "both supported" in the first if statement.  Both zooms are supported as I have checked before.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.CAMERA_ZOOM_CONTROLS);
    params = mCamera.getParameters();

    Log.i("zoomControl", "assignement done");



        if (params.isZoomSupported() && params.isSmoothZoomSupported()) {
            //most phones

            maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();

            zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true); 
            Log.i("here", "both supported");
            zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);




            zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
                        currentZoomLevel++;
                        mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);

                    }
                }
            });

            zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
                        currentZoomLevel--;
                        mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (params.isZoomSupported() && !params.isSmoothZoomSupported()){
            Log.i("here", "zoom supported and smooth not supported");

            maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();



            zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
            zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

            zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
                        currentZoomLevel++;
                        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);

                    }
                }
            });

            zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
                        currentZoomLevel--;
                        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            //no zoom on phone
            Log.i("here", "no zoom");

            zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Log.i("here", "try");

            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // intentionally left blank for a test
    }



}//end of surfacechanged method
```

Here is my declaration of zoom control in my xml

```
<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/CAMERA_ZOOM_CONTROLS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here is the log:

11-20 17:26:00.667: I/here(22140): start, assignment done
11-20 17:26:00.667: D/AndroidRuntime(22140): Shutting down VM
11-20 17:26:00.667: W/dalvikvm(22140): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416118b0)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at com.cellf.smartfieldtester.CameraPreview.surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:68)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:833)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5509)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-20 17:26:00.677: E/AndroidRuntime(22140):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please find the exception in the `adb logcat` logs. Nothe that there usually is a "caused by" part. It will show the line numbers, most likely, the recipient object is null. If you cannot find the problem after that, post the log here.

Comment: please check the log.

Comment: What is line 68 in CameraPreview.java?

Comment: I fixed it.  Basically I had to define the zoomcontrols in photo taking class and pass ZoomControl as a parameter to the camera preview constructor.  the photo taking class is where framelayout is addressed.